# How do I shorten the formula for comparing two dates in excel standard date format?

Tags: excel, date, compare, excel-2010

I have created a formula to compare two dates. M673 is a date that is manually entered but sometime copied over which leaves that unnecessary " "in the front from time to time which makes the date extraction difficult (that's why I trimmed it). The date in N673 is extracted from a manually entered period (i.e. 08/2015) 08 is actually October (10). The extraction formula looks as follows:

```
(N673)=IF(A673="","",DATE(RIGHT(A673,4),LEFT(A673,2)+3,))
```

This is to ensure it updates for every period posted automatically.

The below formula says if M673 is before N673 but on the first day of that month and year, then it becomes 1 else its a 0.
Any way to shorten the below formula?

```
(G673)=IF(DATE(LEFT(TEXT(TRIM(M673),"yyyy-mm-dd"),4),MID(TEXT(TRIM(M673),"yyyy-mm-dd"),6,2),RIGHT(TEXT(TRIM(M673),"yyyy-mm-dd"),2))<(DATE(LEFT(TEXT(N673,"yyyy-mm-dd"),4),MID(TEXT(N673,"yyyy-mm-dd"),6,2),1)),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `DATEVALUE`?  The following should work for the scenario you have described above.

```
(G673)=IF(DATEVALUE(TRIM(M673))<N673,1,0)
```

There's no need to create a new date based on all the parts.  This is what `DATEVALUE` will do for you automatically.

Comment: Answer updated as a result of testing to give accurate answer